# Custom localization file with Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, localization, globalization

I am trying to add custom localization file with name Localization.employee.resx, my web application has some other languages and resource files: Localization.ar.resx, Localization.fr.resx etc... 
For switching the languages I use global.asax file with the code:

```
string cultureName = SessionService.GetUser().Language.CultureName;

var ci = new CultureInfo(cultureName);
ci.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ci;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
```

What is the best way to use my localization file Localization.employee.resx if cultureName variable is "employee".

I tried to use CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder but I heard it is bad way for using since it will require admin privileges for the website pool. And also can't find the assembly which has this CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder class. 
Please advice, spent on it long time.